# How to write sql query for cosmos db with random number as key?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to query cosmos db where i want to fetch all document where user_list has **"13" : true**

i want to execute something like this but this sql query is not working i want to know how i can query this document. ***select * from c where c.user_list.13=true***

```
this is an example document:
     {
          "id": "45923e73-05a8-49e3-9339-1648830d1475",
          "client_id": "999999",
          "user_list": {
            "1": true,
            "2": true,
            "3": true,
            "5": true,
            "6": true,
            "7": true,
            "8": true,
            "9": true,
            "10": true,
            "11": true,
            "12": true,
            "13": true,
            "14": true,
            "15": true
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this SQL:

```
select * from c where c.user_list['13']=true
```

Comment: hmm its was pretty simple.

Comment: i just want to ask one point this sql query internally do any array search in user_list or its something like hash map?

Comment: SQL query in Cosmos DB is as a JSON query language. This SQL query is more like hash map search.